# Can't catch the members of the server

Tags: javascript, discord

This is my code
/pick +topic name +identity group +randomly draw 2 people

For example: Who will buy the food for dinner today @Colleagues Group 2
Response: Who will buy the food for dinner today? Group of colleagues: big a, small b

But I can't seem to catch the members
Members with Role: 0
But it seems that my robot permissions have been given.

I don’t know much about programming, I just pieced it together and read online articles and asked gpt to write it.
There seems to be no way to move the permissions to the highest level.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('pick')
    .setDescription('根據身分組抽選成員')
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option.setName('topic')
        .setDescription('主題')
        .setRequired(true))
    .addRoleOption(option =>
      option.setName('role')
        .setDescription('身分組')
        .setRequired(true))
    .addIntegerOption(option =>
      option.setName('num')
        .setDescription('人數')
        .setRequired(true)),

  async execute(interaction) {
    try {
      const topic = interaction.options.getString('topic');
      const selectedRole = interaction.options.getRole('role');
      const num = interaction.options.getInteger('num');
      
      console.log('Selected Role ID:', selectedRole.id);
      
      const membersWithRole = await getMembersByRole(interaction.guild, selectedRole);
      console.log('Members with Role:', membersWithRole.size);

      if (membersWithRole.size < num) {
        await interaction.reply('身分組成員數量不足，請重新設定人數。');
        return;
      }
      
      const membersArray = membersWithRole.array();

      const pickedMembers = getRandomMembers(membersArray, num);

      if (pickedMembers.length === 0) {
        await interaction.reply('未選中任何成員，請檢查身分組是否有成員。');
        return;
      }

      await interaction.reply(`主題: ${topic}。抽中:\n${pickedMembers}`);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      await interaction.reply('發生錯誤，請稍後再試!');
    }
  }
};

async function getMembersByRole(guild, role) {
  try {
    const members = await guild.members.fetch({ query: role.id });
    return members;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('找不到身分組成員。');
  }
}

function getRandomMembers(members, num) {
  const pickedMembers = [];
  const shuffledMembers = members.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5); 

  for (let i = 0; i < num && i < shuffledMembers.length; i++) {
    const member = shuffledMembers[i];
    pickedMembers.push(`<@${member.id}>`);
  }

  return pickedMembers.join('\n');
}
```

Comment: Why did you include description in 2 languages?